# Amazon S3 static website doesn't serve js

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I've uploaded my .js file from several diferent method:

- S3 Management Console
- S3Fox Organizer
- Python Boto Command Line

In all cases, i couldn't made it work from my html call, it just doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/myBuket/myJavascript.js">
```

*But if i put the URL in web Browsers, i can see my Javascript code.*

1. I've modified the mime type traying with "text/javascript" and "application/x-javascript" both in Amazon S3 Bucket and my html... nothing.
2. I've modified the protocol in the call (http vs https) and nothing at all.

If i put my Javascript inside my html it does work, so, the code isn't the problem. I can make work a image from a url, for example, but no a javascript.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean S3 doesn't serve any Javascript or just your particular Javascript code?  Try hosting something that does work reliably well, for example a basic jQuery demo.

Comment: i've tried with a simple code like `<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Hello World"); </script>` and nothing...

Comment: Define functions in the S3 hosted script and call them from HTML, the problems you are experiencing are due when and how the script is being executed before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks man! i was losted with that... but i can't find a way to call a javascript function from a url. Can you give me a example of that? I read about "Bookmarklet" but it doesn't seem your point.

Comment: [This example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event2.shtml) may be informative, uses the `onclick` event handler.